# How do you escape shell arguments for a subcomand?

Tags: shell, shell-script

Say you're writing a shell script.  It takes an arbitrary number of command line arguments and passes them to a command line utility.  When calling that utility, each argument needs to be prefixed with a flag.  What's the correct way to escape this in your script, so that the utility sees the exact same strings that the shell script does?

Concrete example: passing regular expressions to `grep`. You run your wrapper script:

```
./findit.sh needle "old socks" "spare change"
```

And you expect `grep` to be called with those arguments as match expressions:

```
grep haystack.txt -e needle -e "old socks" -e "spare change"
```

It's the `-e` prefix that complicates things; if it wasn't necessary, you could just use `"$@"`.  What does your script need to do to make sure that `grep` gets its arguments properly escaped?  Is there a portable way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a working version in Bash, but it uses Bash arrays, and I strongly suspect it's not portable:

```
for arg in "$@"; do
  args+=("-e" "$arg")
done

grep haystack.txt "${args[@]}"
```